# remove italics from align

Tags: align, italic

```
\begin{align*}
P2P &- Peer-to-Peer Network\\
%.....
\end{align*}
```

I have a Abbreviation page in my PDF. For aligning all the '-' I am using align*.
All the content inside align shows up in italics.
How do I make the content inside align appear normal and not italic?

Comment: [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text{...}` for text-related content, which this clearly is. You may also consider `tabular` as an alternative.

Comment: How do I align inside a \text after every '-'  ?

Comment: To have a list of acronyms you might also consider the [`nomencl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment `align(*)` is a math-related environment. You should use a `tabular` environment: with the header as below, you will probably get what you want.

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{ --- }l}
P2P & Peer-to-Peer Network\\
%.....
\end{tabular}
```

If your list becomes longer than one page, consider using package `longtable` or similar.